# how to scroll screen on particular input using React Native

Tags: react-native

I am developing react native app. I have set Input fields as a registration form and trying to add validations. On Press submit button if the fields are empty than its highlight the input fields with red border and its working but not rotating the screen to the empty field. i want to scroll screen to the empty input fields on press submit button.
here is my code:-

```
<Input label="First Name"
                              value={this.state.fname}
                               marginTop={23}
                               borderColor={this.state.bgcolor}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this, 'fname')}  
                              ref='scrollfname'

                        />

                            <Input label="Last Name"
                                value={this.state.lname}
                                marginTop={23}
                                borderColor={this.state.bgcolor1}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this, 'lname')}
                        />
                         <Input label="E-Mail Address"
                               value={this.state.email}
                               placeholder="example@gmail.com"
                               marginTop={23}
                               borderColor={this.state.bgcolor2}
                               onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this, 'email')}
                        />
                        <Text style={productStyle.detail}>Company Details</Text>

                          <Text style={productStyle.detail}>Your Address</Text>
                           <Input label="Street Address"
                               value={this.state.street}
                                marginTop={23}
                                borderColor={this.state.bgcolor3}
                               onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this, 'street')}
                        />
                         <Input label="City"
                                value={this.state.city}
                                marginTop={23}
                                borderColor={this.state.bgcolor4}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this, 'city')}
                        />

                          <Text style={productStyle.detail}>Your Contact Information</Text>
                            <Input label="Telephone Number"
                               value={this.state.phone}
                                marginTop={23}
                                borderColor={this.state.bgcolor7}
                               onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this, 'phone')}
                        />
<View style={productStyle.greenBT}>
            <Text onPress={this.handePressSignIn.bind(this)} style={{fontSize:13,fontWeight:"lighter",textAlign:'center',color:'#fff'}}>{<Icon name="user"/>} Continue</Text>              
        </View>
```

here is function:-

```
  handePressSignIn() {
        if(this.state.fname == ""){
            this.setState({bgcolor:'#ff0000'});             

            return false;
            }
        else if(this.state.lname == ""){
            this.setState({bgcolor1:'#ff0000'});
            return false;
            }
}
```

how can i scroll screen to the empty Input field. when i clicked submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Embed your view into a scrollview component:

```
<ScrollView ... >
    <YourView>
    ...
    </YourView>
</ScrollView>
```

call the below method to scroll to certain position:

```
scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
```

What you need is to calculate the x and y offset to scroll.

Comment: how can i calculate the X and Y offset ?

Comment: that is your business logic related to your detailed layout, I can hardly help.